# Multiple levels of methods (or dot-notation) in Ruby

Tags: ruby, oop, rubygems

I saw a RubyGem with the following use:

```
f = Foo.new("joe")
f.say.hello #=> "Hello joe"
```

In [my Gem](http://github.com/eturk/dance), I'm trying to have the same syntax. I have many classes within the Module Dance, but once I create a new instance of Dance::Client, I can't access the other Classes. For example:

```
d = Dance::Client.new("key")
d::Genres.all # => errors out
```

The results I would like is:

```
d = Dance::Client.new("key")
d.genres.all
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's probably dozens of ways you could do this, so here's a few examples:

**Client instance method returns Genre class**

```
module Dance
  class Client
    def genres
      Genre
    end
  end

  class Genre
    def self.all
      # return all genres
    end
  end
end
```

**Client instance method returns Genre collection class**

```
module Dance
  class Client
    def genres
      GenreCollection.new
    end
  end

  class GenreCollection
    def all
      Genre.all
    end
  end

  class Genre
    def self.all
      # return all genres
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

In the example you show, "say" is an instance method, returning something with a "hello" method.

Similarly, "genres" would be an instance property of a Dance module's Client instance.

If you're just trying to instantiate a client class you'd use Module:: Class notation, whereas your error example attempts to do that with an instance.

Comment: I think I understand what you mean, also with help from this post (http://railstips.org/blog/archives/2009/05/11/class-and-instance-methods-in-ruby/). But, could you provide some code?